# How to create a push notification with cordova 3.3 step to step?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-3

I want to implement push notifications in android using 3.3 cordova, I'm new at this. I have tried several tutorials but without success. 
Could explain a simple way to implement it step by step?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add this plugin in your cordova

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

And you can use php to send the messages

Replace api key generated by server key in console google cloud messaging.

```
class Pusher
{
    const GOOGLE_GCM_URL = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    private $apiKey;
    private $proxy;
    private $output;

    public function __construct($apiKey, $proxy = null)
    {
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->proxy  = $proxy;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|array $regIds
     * @param string $data
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function notify($regIds, $data)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::GOOGLE_GCM_URL);
        if (!is_null($this->proxy)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->getHeaders());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->getPostFields($regIds, $data));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === false) {
            throw new \Exception(curl_error($ch));
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        $this->output = $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOutputAsArray()
    {
        return json_decode($this->output, true);
    }

    /**
     * @return object
     */
    public function getOutputAsObject()
    {
        return json_decode($this->output);
    }

    private function getHeaders()
    {
        return [
            'Authorization: key=' . $this->apiKey,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];
    }

    private function getPostFields($regIds, $data)
    {
        $fields = [
            'registration_ids' => is_string($regIds) ? [$regIds] : $regIds,
            'data'             => is_string($data) ? ['message' => $data] : $data,
        ];

        return json_encode($fields, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}
```

There are alot of examples of this plugins. Also in the same https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git is the documentation